# In scipy, what's the point of the two different distance functions used in hierarchical clustering?

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

There is one distance function I can pass to `pdist` use to create the distance matrix that is given to `linkage`. There is a second distance function that I can pass to `linkage` as the metric.

Why are there two possible distance functions?

If they are different, how are they used? For instance, does linkage use the distances in the distance matrix for its initial iterations, i.e. to see if any two original observations should be combined into a cluster, and then use the metric function for further combinations, i.e. of two clusters or of a cluster with an original observation?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html  From the parameters section, it looks like pdist is the default distance function, and it gives you the option to specify your own, which for instance could be dimensionally weighted.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieHaley. However, my question is about that fact that you can specify a custom function twice, once when creating the distance matrix and once when doing the linkage -- why twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one distance function is ever used.

If you pass a 1D condensed distance matrix (i.e the output of `pdist`) to `linkage`, then `linkage` will ignore its `metric` parameter. (See [source code here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py#L636-L640) where scipy calls the relevant underlying Cython linkage function without ever using the `metric` parameter.)

On the other hand, if you pass in a 2D matrix, `linkage` will treat this matrix as observation and invoke `pdist` on this matrix for you, using the  `metric` parameter as the distance function. (See [source code here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py#L648).)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter 'method' is used to measure the similarities between clusters through the hierarchical clustering process. The parameter 'metric' is used to measure the distance between two objects in the dataset.

The 'metric' is closely related to the nature of the data (e.g., you could want to use 'euclidean' distance for objects with the same number of features, or Dynamic Time Warping for time series with different durations).

The thing is that there are two ways of using the linkage function. The first parameter is y, and it can be either the data itself or a distance matrix produced previously by a given measure.

If you choose to feed 'linkage' with a distance matrix, then you won't need the 'metric' parameter, because you have already calculated all the distance between all objects.